# Disable touch bar when taking a screen shot in macOS with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, terminal

I'm making a simple macOS screenshot to clipboard application with **swift** for a university project and, to perform the screenshots, I'm using the **screencapture** utility from macOS.

What I have is a function like this one:

```
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        let pipe = Pipe()
        
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = pipe
        
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        task.launch()
        
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

        return output
}
```

And then I have a button that calls the function:

```
shell("screencapture -i -c")
```

The problem is that when the button is clicked, the screen capture utility is indeed called, **however** my mackbook pro touchbar is activated with the utility UI, which I don't want since there are options that the user is not supposed to have.

So, the **question is:** how can I disable the touchbar when the **shell** method is called?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the process ID `pid` of the `touchbar` using

```
ps -e | grep "ControlStrip"
```

Then you can stop it temporarily using the command

```
 kill -STOP pid
```

Then after that you can reactivate the touch ID using

```
kill -CONT pid
```

This technique won't turn off the `touchbar` but rather will freeze it (touch won't work). No action can be taken using `touchbar` unless it is resumed.

One liner to get process ID of touchbar in terminal:

```
pid=$(ps -e | grep "ControlStrip" | awk 'NR==1{print $1}');
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer!:) Unfortunately I can't perform the kill comand, as every time I obtain the PID (with the first command), the moment after the PID for the touchbar process changed, I don't know why...:/

Comment: Could you tell me, what is the ouput of `ps -e | grep "ControlStrip" | awk '{print $1}'`command?

Comment: Sure! The output is two lines with two numbers! Removing the 'awk' part I get: 1) "481 ??         0:01.03 /System/Library/CoreServices/ControlStrip.app/Contents/MacOS/ControlStrip"
and then ->  "843 ttys001    0:00.00 grep ControlStrip". Furthermore, If I try to perform the kill command, I can only do it for the first PID (481 in this example), but the touchbar keeps reacting to my touch! If I try to kill the second PID i obtain the message "failed: no such process", and the PID changes! Thank you!

Comment: I believe, the first `pid` is always the same irrespective of the times the command has executed. If that is the case, then the constant `pid` is for touchbar and the second `pid` (the changing one) is the process id of `grep`.

Comment: Yes, it is! But even after performing the "kill -STOP" the touch bar reacts to my finger and changes it's GUI.